# Latex multicols how to change printing sequence

Tags: pdftex, multicol, exam

I'm using Latex multicols to print list of data. Current mode of printing is mentioned below. Can you please help to get change printing sequence.

[image]

Comment: you could use multicols* or simply use the standard `[twocolumn]` option with no package. Balancing the columns to produce the first layout is the whole point of multicol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `multicols*`

```
\documentclass {article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
  \lipsum[1-2]
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

[image]